# Join several dataframes on an empty dataframe with fixed index, merging columns or appending those

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I have a dataframe with a range index and no data, in real data the index is a time range.

E.g.

```
df_main = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.RangeIndex(0,15,1))
```

See Fig1

And I have several dataframes which varying columns and indexes, I just want to join those on the main dataframe based on index:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2, 3, 5]}, index = pd.RangeIndex(0,4,1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [5, 6, 7, 8]}, index = pd.RangeIndex(4,8,1))
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'value2': [9, 8, 7, 6]}, index = pd.RangeIndex(0,4,1))
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'value': [1, 2],'value2': [3, 4],'value3': [5, 6]}, index = pd.RangeIndex(10,12,1))
```

See Fig 2,3,4,5

I tried concat:

```
display(pd.concat([df_main,df1,df2,df3,df4]))
```

Which gives me the unwanted output you can see in Fig 6.

I also tried join which results in an error I did not understand:

```
ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: Index(['value', 'value2'], dtype='object')
```

What I want to is the output you can see in Fig7.

[image: Figures]

Comment: try pandas **merge** method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the index and aggregate with [`first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first.html):

```
pd.concat([df_main, df1, df2, df3, df4]).groupby(level=0).first()
```

[out]

```
    value  value2  value3
0     1.0     9.0     NaN
1     2.0     8.0     NaN
2     3.0     7.0     NaN
3     5.0     6.0     NaN
4     5.0     NaN     NaN
5     6.0     NaN     NaN
6     7.0     NaN     NaN
7     8.0     NaN     NaN
8     NaN     NaN     NaN
9     NaN     NaN     NaN
10    1.0     3.0     5.0
11    2.0     4.0     6.0
12    NaN     NaN     NaN
13    NaN     NaN     NaN
14    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks!both approaches from Sandeep and you work, but yours has a better performance 5ms against 9ms

Answer (score 2):

Use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html#pandas.DataFrame.combine_first):

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce((lambda x, y: x.combine_first(y)), [df_main,df1,df2,df3,df4])

print(df)

    value  value2  value3
0     1.0     9.0     NaN
1     2.0     8.0     NaN
2     3.0     7.0     NaN
3     5.0     6.0     NaN
4     5.0     NaN     NaN
5     6.0     NaN     NaN
6     7.0     NaN     NaN
7     8.0     NaN     NaN
8     NaN     NaN     NaN
9     NaN     NaN     NaN
10    1.0     3.0     5.0
11    2.0     4.0     6.0
12    NaN     NaN     NaN
13    NaN     NaN     NaN
14    NaN     NaN     NaN
```